# FullCalendar not rendering all events through AJAX/JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I've been messing around with FullCalendar for a while now, but I have a slight issue. If I load events through AJAX/JSON in the correct format the calendar only renders the first event.

All other events are showing in the `console.log` call, but the calendar only shows the first one. The sample events code from documentation is as follows:

```
events: [{
    title: 'My Event',
    start: '2010-01-01',
    url: 'http://google.com/'
  },
  {
    title: 'My Event',
    start: '2010-01-02',
    url: 'http://google.com/'
  }
  // other events here
],
```

My code is below:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
  function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "/tande/fetch_holidays/",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      var events = [];
      $.map(data.holidays, function(value) {
        console.log(value)
        description = value.toString().split('_')[0]
        start_date = value.toString().split('_')[1]
        end_date = value.toString().split('_')[2]
        person = value.toString().split('_')[3]
        events.push({
          title: person,
          start: start_date,
          end: end_date
        });
        callback(events);
        console.log(events);
      })
    },
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback to events was placed too early. Correct code below:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
  function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "/tande/fetch_holidays/",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      var events = [];
      $.map(data.holidays, function(value) {
        console.log(value)
        description = value.toString().split('_')[0]
        start_date = value.toString().split('_')[1]
        end_date = value.toString().split('_')[2]
        person = value.toString().split('_')[3]
        events.push({
          title: person + ' - ' + description,
          start: start_date,
          end: end_date,
        });
      })
      callback(events);
    },
  })
},
```